# Routing not working for my AJAX request

Tags: python, ajax, django, url-routing

I currently have a url pattern defined as follows:

```
    url(r'^potato/(?P<slug1>[-\w])/(?P<slug2>[-\w]+)/potatoajax/$', views.potatoajax, name='potatoajax'),
```

and in my views a function:

```
def potatoajax(request):
  print 'Potato Ajax'
  if request.method == 'POST':
    print 'more potatoes'
  else:
    print 'dont print Potato AJax'
```

My ajax request is as follows:

```
var url = 'potatoajax/'; 
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: {
          'hello': 'hello world',
          'csrfmiddlewaretoken': getToken(),
        },
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
          $('#message').html(data.message);
        }
```

However, I keep getting 404's on my requests =( I strongly suspect this is related to my routing in the url pattern, but have no idea how to correct this.

here is the error message:

```
POST http://localhost:8000/potato/potato1/potato2/potatoajax/ 404 (Not Found)
```

If I modify the url to the follwoing as suggested:

```
url(r'^potato/(?P<slug1>[-\w]+)/(?P<slug2>[-\w]+)/potatoajax/$', views.potatoajax, name='potatoajax'),
```

I get a 500 POST due to a TypeError at /potato/potato1/potato2/potatoajax/
potatoajax() got an unexpected keyword argument 'slug2'.

However, this is another problem, so I will post another question if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your urls.py

You don't have a multiplier for slug1

```
url(r'^potato/(?P<slug1>[-\w]+)/(?P<slug2>[-\w]+)/potatoajax/$', views.potatoajax, name='potatoajax'),
```

And your views will accept two more arguments as.

```
def potatoajax(request, slug1, slug2):
  print 'Potato Ajax'
  if request.method == 'POST':
    print 'more potatoes'
  else:
    print 'dont print Potato AJax'
```

Comment: thanks, I modified the question based on what you just provided, however, since it is a completely different issue, your anwser is appreciated!

Comment: Thanks anyways updated the answer a bit. see it it works.

Comment: hehe, it is what i did, thanks for the follow up thought, very much appreciated